# Лишние пустые строки при записи в csv файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, csv, beautiful-soup

Код:

```py
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_resp(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return resp.text


def write_csv(data):
    with open('proxy.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        
        writer.writerow([
                data['ip'],
                data['port']
            ])


def get_page(html):
    sp = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    trs = sp.find('table', id='proxylisttable').find('tbody').find_all('tr')[:3]
    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        ip = tds[0].text
        port = tds[1].text
        data = {'ip': ip,'port': port}
        write_csv(data)
```

Пропускает строку после итерации:

[image: Пропускает строку после итерации]

Как это исправить?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 11):

Попробуйте в контекст чтения файла добавить параметр `newline` со значением "" (пустая строка):

```
with open('proxy.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
```

UPD в [доках по csv](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/csv.html#examples) рекомендуют именно так и открывать...

Answer (score 1):

Просто перед заливкой удалите пустые строки. Попробуйте пандас

```
import pandas as pd
df[pd.notnull(df['Любой столбец'])]
```

и сформировать `csv` там можете

```
df=[] # какойто дата врейм
pd.df.to_csv()
```